# Getting multiple super's

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to walk up the hierarchy tree multiple steps? For example:

```js
class First {
    constructor(word) {this.word = word};
    print() {
        console.log('1', this.word);
    } 
}

class Second extends First {
    constructor(word) {super(word);}
    print() {
        super.print();
        console.log('2', this.word);
    }
}

class Third extends Second {
    constructor(word) {super(word);}
    print() {
        // super.super.print();
        super.print(); // this works to get to the top, but possible to get to the top directly?
        console.log('3', this.word);
    }
}

let t = new Third('Hello');
t.print();
```

In other words, what I'd like is it to do:

```
super.super.print();
// 1. hello
super.print();
// 1. hello
// 2. hello
console.log('3', this.word);
// 3. hello
```

Comment: It would be illegal regarding the overriding methods etc. why would you want to use such thing?

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN I wouldn't -- I was jus curious, I basically thought `this` returned the current instance, `parent` would return the parent instance, and `parent.parent....` would return that one.